# How to pass values to my object array from my static method

Tags: java, arrays, object, static-methods

I have 3 classes one EyMain that is my main class where I read a **"n" value > 100**  that creates the number of my object arrays.Then I call  **writeUSB() method** where I fill the object array.

```
public class EyMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n;

        do {       
            System.out.println("Give an integer value > 100 : ");
            n = scannerUserInput.getInteger();
        } while (n < 101);

        ekpaideytikoYliko usb[] = new ekpaideytikoYliko[n];

        eYMethods.writeUSB(usb);
        eYMethods.showDocs(usb);

        } 
}
```

My other class is eYMethods where I have my 2 static methods **writeUSB** that I want to return the pointer of the last element that have stored in my array because I want to check if my **memorySpace > 8gb I want to remove it from the array and updating the last element of the array** and **showDocs**   that I want to print only the elements from the object array that the user has typed and print only the file extension with **.doc or .docx** .

```
package eymain;

public class eYMethods {

static double writeUSB(ekpaideytikoYliko usb[]) {

    for(int i = 0; i < usb.length; i++) {      

        System.out.println("Give fileName : ");
        usb[i].setFileName(scannerUserInput.getString());
        System.out.println("Give minutes : ");
        usb[i].setMinutes(scannerUserInput.getDouble());
        System.out.println("Give memorySpace");
        usb[i].setMemorySpace(scannerUserInput.getDouble());
    }


    return 0;

}
static void showDocs(ekpaideytikoYliko usb[]) {

    for(int i =0; i < usb.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("fileName : " + usb[i].getFileName());
        System.out.println("minutes : " + usb[i].getMinutes());
        System.out.println("memorySpace : " + usb[i].getMemorySpace());
    }
}}
```

And last class is my ekapideytikoYliko that I have my private variables, get and set, my constructor and a String method getFileType that I want to take from the fileName the extension from it. Example(.doc, .docx, .mp4).

```
package eymain;

public class ekpaideytikoYliko {

private String fileName;
private double minutes;
private double memorySpace;

ekpaideytikoYliko(String fileName, double minutes, double memorySpace) {

    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.minutes = minutes;
    this.memorySpace = memorySpace;

}

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public double getMinutes() {
    return minutes;
}

public void setMinutes(double minutes) {
    this.minutes = minutes;
}

public double getMemorySpace() {
    return memorySpace;
}

public void setMemorySpace(double memorySpace) {
    this.memorySpace = memorySpace;
}

String getfileType(ekpaideytikoYliko usb[]) {

    int name = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (name == -1) {
        return "";
    }
    return fileName.substring(name);
}}
```

And my scannerUserInput file :

```
package eymain;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class scannerUserInput {

    static int getInteger(){
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
      try{
    int i = ob.nextInt();
        return i;
      }
      catch(Exception e){
    return -1;
      }
}

    static byte getByte(){
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
      try{
    byte b = ob.nextByte();
        return b;
      }
      catch(Exception e){
    return -1;
      }
}
    static short getShort(){
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
      try{
    short s = ob.nextShort();
        return s;
      }
      catch(Exception e){
    return -1;
      }
}
    static long getLongInteger(){
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
      try{
    long l = ob.nextLong();
        return l;
      }
      catch(Exception e){
    return -1;
      }
}
    static float getFloat(){
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
      try{
    float f = ob.nextFloat();
        return f;
      }
      catch(Exception e){
    return -1;
      }
}
    static double getDouble(){
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
      try{
    double d = ob.nextDouble();
        return d;
      }
      catch(Exception e){
    return -1;
      }
}
    static String getString(){
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
      try{
    String s = ob.nextLine();
        return s;
      }
      catch(Exception e){
    return "";
      }
}

    static char getChar(){
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
      try{
    char ch = ob.next().charAt(0);
        return ch;
      }
      catch(Exception e){
    return ' ';
      }
}    

}
```

When I type inside the **writeUSB**  method the data from the scanner I get an error in my first type.

Comment: " i get an error in my first type."  - Note: when asking about errors you should post them in the most complete form possible, i.e. if you have a stacktrace post that as well and if it mentions lines in code you've posted mark those lines so that we don't have to guess.

Comment: Please provide the error you are getting. I believe you need to flush the scanner with `java.util.Scanner.nextLine()` after your other calls.

Comment: if you used the scanner you will get an error cause its a file that i have inside my project that has all the types of variables . I suggest you to use  the default scanner

Comment: Give an integer value > 100 : 
105
Give fileName : 
file
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at eymain.eYMethods.writeUSB(eYMethods.java:10)
 at eymain.EyMain.main(EyMain.java:16)      this is my error message

Comment: Seems like the issue is with `scannerUserInput`. I can't seem to find ScannerUserInput Methods/Class in the code you provided above.

Comment: The scanner on me works great i didn't mention it cause it shouldn't bother your just write example :  Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Give fileName");

Comment: Here i updated with the scannerUserInputFile you can copy and paste it and use it also.

Comment: I guess you were right the issue wasn't scannerUserInputFile. Anyways I would suggest you to start all class names with an uppercase. It should be ScannerUserInputFile. This makes it easier to distinguish between an instance of class and the class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java when you create an array of an object in your case it is:

```
ekpaideytikoYliko usb[] = new ekpaideytikoYliko[n];
```

Java Simply does this

```
// Lets say n = 5 for easier demonstration
{null, null, null, null, null}
```

Source: [Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

> For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null.

Now when in `eYMethods` when you try do call a method it just return nullpointer because that element is null. To fix that you need to create an object and store that object in array. Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < usb.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Give fileName : ");
    String fileName = scannerUserInput.getString();
    System.out.println("Give minutes : ");
    double minutes = scannerUserInput.getDouble();
    System.out.println("Give memorySpace");
    double memorySpace = scannerUserInput.getDouble();
    ekpaideytikoYliko tempEkpaideytikoYliko = new ekpaideytikoYliko(fileName, minutes, memorySpace);
    usb[i] = tempEkpaideytikoYliko;
}
```

Now java will create an Object of Class `ekpaideytikoYliko` and store it in array.

Comment: Thanks this worked . I wanted the temp object array that you did its the same with usb after your make it equal  usb[i] = tempEkpaideytikoYliko;  , right? So the setters aren't necessary?

Comment: @LazosPap While it may not be necessary right now. They might come in handy if you want to expand on this code. So I suggest you keep them. Besides that you are using getters in `showDocs`.

Comment: One other thing that i want to achieve is to show the total memory of the usb so if the usb memory > 8 gb(8000mb  i want to count it as mb)  and its the last object that override the 8 gb i want this to remove from the array and there is a chance that the object array will not be filled full i want the writeUSB to return the pointer of the last element. How can i achieve that?

Comment: @LazosPap I would suggest that you keep track of memory and objects stored in array and if the memory goes above limit then you can simply skip over the rest of the objects. Though I do not understand "return the pointer of last element?". Java doesn't have pointers. Even it does what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Should i do that if condition inside the for that i fill the object array?

Comment: @LazosPap Yes. Put the variables above for-loop and update them after each iteration.

Comment: The "pointer" that I am talking is the last element that has stored in the array that i want to be returned from my static double writeUSB method

Comment: Create a variable called `noOfObjects` and increment it whenever you add an object in array. After the loop has executed. Return that variable.

Comment: Okay i have create `noOfObjects` and i increment it . My if is kinda my problem cause I don't know how to remove the object after my variable sumMemory pass the limit. So far i have this : `if (sumMemory > 80) {
                System.out.println("overLimit");`

Comment: if `sumMemory` is above limit. Just skip over the rest of objects instead of writing and then deleting them. You can use `continue` to go to next iteration without executing the code beneath it or `break` or get out of loop altogether at that line.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help really appreciate it I will try it when I will sit in my pc

Comment: @LazosPap Np. Can you vote on the answer or Stack Overflow doesn't allow you to do it?

Comment: I can't vote I don't have 15 rep and above I have marked it as solution only