# Object Array point null

Tags: java, arrays, object, static-methods

My **eYMethods** class has 2 static methods the first one is **writeUSB** that fills my object array with my scanner and I want to stop creating object arrays `if (sumMemory > 80)` and delete the object that passed the condition. But when I do that, my second static method showDocs that I call in my main class points null cause example: (if I create 2 object arrays and the first one override the condition of sumMemory, the second object array waits from my getters some values so it points null ). How can I fix that?

```
package eymain;

public class eYMethods {

    static int writeUSB(ekpaideytikoYliko usb[]) {

        double sumMemory = 0 ;
        int noOfObjects = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < usb.length; i++) {                  
            System.out.println("Δωσε fileName : ");
            String fileName = scannerUserInput.getString();
            System.out.println("Δωσε minutes : ");
            double minutes = scannerUserInput.getDouble();
            System.out.println("Δωσε memorySpace");
            double memorySpace = scannerUserInput.getDouble();
            System.out.println();
            ekpaideytikoYliko tempEkpaideytikoYliko = new ekpaideytikoYliko(fileName, minutes, memorySpace);
            usb[i] = tempEkpaideytikoYliko;
            noOfObjects++;
            sumMemory += memorySpace;
            if (sumMemory > 80) {  
                noOfObjects--;                
                System.out.println("OverLimit");
                break;               
            }
        }

        System.out.println("sumMemory : " + sumMemory);
        return noOfObjects;

    }
    static void showDocs(ekpaideytikoYliko usb[]) {

        for(int i =0; i < usb.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("fileName : " + usb[i].getFileName());
            System.out.println("minutes : " + usb[i].getMinutes());
            System.out.println("memorySpace : " + usb[i].getMemorySpace());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: what's your ```ekpaideytikoYliko```?

Comment: You probably need to post a valid [mre]

Comment: Its my object array that i have created in another class i have posted a similar question with all my code here  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57728654/how-to-pass-values-to-my-object-array-from-my-static-method) check it there so i don't duplicate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so it looks like the problem is occurring because `usb[i]` is `null` and you trying to do this:

```
 System.out.println("fileName : " + usb[i].getFileName());
```

which will attempt to call a method on `null` and give you an NPE.

Solution #1: test for null.

```
static void showDocs(ekpaideytikoYliko usb[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < usb.length && usb[i] != null; i++) {
         ....
    }
}
```

Solution #2: pass in and use `noOfObjects`

```
static void showDocs(ekpaideytikoYliko usb[], int noOfObjects) {
    for (int i = 0; i < usb.noOfObjects; i++) {
         ....
    }
}
```

Solution #3: use `List<ekpaideytikoYliko>` instead of `ekpaideytikoYliko[]`

This is cleanest because it solves another problem as well.  If you use a `List`, you don't have to preallocate an array that is "large enough", and hope that it is.

---

Style.

According to Google translate, "ekpaideytikoYliko" is two words: probably εκπαιδευτικ Υλικο, transliterated into Roman characters.  So the correct class name should be:

```
  EkpaideytikoYliko
```

A Class name should *always* start with an uppercase letter.

or some variation

Comment: Thanks very much I don't get the error it was so simple but couldn't think of it.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but i don't think solution #2 will Not work since his ```ekpaideytikoYliko ``` class doesn't expose a member (or a get method) for ```noOfObjects```

Comment: @DanielK - I am suggesting he passes it as a second parameter.  Look at the new method signature.

Comment: ohh yeah correct i didn't notice that,sorry.

Comment: Its Greek word and its for a homework I didn't create that variables I'm following the exercise.

Comment: Ah ... well your teacher needs a lesson in Java style then!  http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/f11/style_guide.html

Comment: Sure he does even in my language i don't really know what he is asking for :D

Comment: Can i ask your one more question about the file extension that I need to return with the showDocs method?

Comment: Without seeing your actual question, here is a hint: find and read at the javadocs for `String.substring` and `String.lastIndexOf`.

Comment: Okay I will try to do it alone

Comment: I tried it with no luck can you help me achieve it? My getfileType method i want to separate the file extension from the dot but when i call inside the `for loop` it doesn't work as i wanted and it shows all the object and not only the doc or docx that i want. `if(usb[i].getfileType(usb) == "doc" || usb[i].getfileType(usb) == "docx")` This is the code that i have inserted in my showDocs inside the `for loop`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, your trying to find a way to not add the `ekpaideytikoYliko tempEkpaideytikoYliko = new ekpaideytikoYliko(fileName, minutes, memorySpace);` to your `usb` array when the `sumMemory` become greater than 80, if that's the case than you can do it easily by addidng the `tempEkpaideytikoYliko` to the array after checking `if sumMemory` is less or equal to 80:

```
static int writeUSB(ekpaideytikoYliko usb[]) {

        double sumMemory = 0 ;
        int noOfObjects = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < usb.length; i++) {                  
            System.out.println("Δωσε fileName : ");
            String fileName = scannerUserInput.getString();
            System.out.println("Δωσε minutes : ");
            double minutes = scannerUserInput.getDouble();
            System.out.println("Δωσε memorySpace");
            double memorySpace = scannerUserInput.getDouble();
            System.out.println();

            sumMemory += memorySpace;
            if (sumMemory > 80) {                 
                System.out.println("OverLimit");
                break;               
            }else{
                ekpaideytikoYliko tempEkpaideytikoYliko = new ekpaideytikoYliko(fileName, minutes, memorySpace);
                usb[i] = tempEkpaideytikoYliko;
                noOfObjects++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("sumMemory : " + sumMemory);
        return noOfObjects;

    }
```

Comment: Yes i don't want to add it but still with your code i still create object arrays after the sumMemory passing the condition. You also forgot the } in the for loop to close it

Comment: I can't execute it I have an error with the continue tag.

Comment: weird, can you please tell me what's the error message?

Comment: I get line error not a loop label: tag

Comment: so weird, try it without the tag(i re-edited it)

Comment: I can  execute it but i get the same error at the end i create 2 object arrays with scanner and I override with the first one the limit and the program doesn't stop there and it keeps going and only at the end of the program shows me the error with the null point. The problem is that usb.length has the value from the main class example to create 2 arrays from the scanner so when the if condition override the getters doesn't update so the showDocs method doesn't know that is 1 array and not 2 since sumMemory has passed the limit

Comment: okay then try it now with a simple ```else``` statement @LazosPap

Comment: It stops when i override the first array but I still get the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` I don't know if its a problem but seems to work right it doesn't show the elements of the array

Comment: that's because in your ```showDocs``` method your loop is for ```usb.length``` and not ```noOfObjects```

Comment: Yeah @Stephen C said clarified it .

Comment: yeah and now i saved you from another error which was 1 extra element in your ```usb``` array :)

Comment: Yeah thanks for your help really appreciate it! I combined your code with @Stephen C for my result

Comment: your welcome mate, also an upvote would be appreciated :)

Comment: I can't cause i don't have 15 rep and above

Comment: ohh, well i helped you with a vote up, good luck mate .

Comment: Thanks mate appreciate it!

Comment: upvoted your other question so now you have 15+ reps :)

Comment: haha thanks i ll upvote you